# Regarding the uniqueness of solutions of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following differential equation,

$$\dot{x} = f(x)$$

and its solution for an initial value $x(0) = x_0$, $x(t; x_0)$. Let's assume that $0$ is a stationary point of $\dot x = f(x)$ and $x(t) = 0$ is obtained through the initial condition $x(0) = 0$, thus $x(t; 0) \equiv 0, \forall t$. Now, let's consider another solution for an initial value $x_1 \neq 0$, $x(t; x_1)$, which reaches $0$ in finite time, say $t_1$. Then, it is said that the uniqueness of solutions is violated. <sup>[[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem#Intuitive_understanding_of_the_theorem)]</sup>

First of all, how is uniqueness defined? The way I understand it, is that for initial values $x_1 \neq x_2 \Rightarrow x(t; x_1) \neq x(t; x_2), \forall t$. However, one could argue that two solutions are different if there exists a time instance $\tau$, where the two solutions differ, i.e. $x(\tau; x_1) \neq x(\tau; x_2)$.

I suppose that uniqueness refers to the former, as in the case of the latter it would not be violated.

My question is why is uniqueness violated? One interpretation I could come up with is that, if there exists an initial value $x_1 \neq 0$ and a time $t_1$ where $x(t_1; x_1) = 0$, then if we use the value of the solution exactly "before" $t_1$, $x(t_1 - dt; x_1)$, as an initial condition, we would have

$$x(t; x(t_1 - dt; x_1)) \equiv 0, \forall t$$

which means we can achieve the trivial trajectory $x(t) =0$ through two different initial values. Besides the abuse of notation, this is more of an intuitive interpretation instead of a proper proof, so could anyone provide a more formal way to prove the uniqueness violation?

Answer (score 0):

Two functions are different if and only if they are different at some point, no discussion here. In case they are also continuous (as solutions of differential equations should be), they will be different at many points, but that is another matter.

On the other hand, your last paragraph explains very clearly (and rigorously) why uniqueness doesn't hold.